# How can I get environment variables defined at script launch in python?

Tags: python, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

## Context

Let's define two types of environmental variables for the sake of this explanation. I am fully aware that this distinction does not actually exist in real life.

Let's call "Pre-defined variables" the variables that are already in the environment at the time of script launch.

"Launch-time variables" are the one defined inline on the script invocation, that only apply to the environment of the process created when launching the script.

Here are some examples:

- Pre-defined variables:

```bash
export var1="value1"
export var2="value2"
# ... more commands
# Now var1 and var3 are in the python process' environment
python script.py args
```

- Launch-defined variables:

```bash
var1="value1" var2="value2" python script.py args
```

---

## My issue

I can use `os.environ` to access variables from my python script.

However I would like to distinguish between "pre-defined" variables and "launch-time" variables inside my python code.

My use case is the following. Suppose I launch a script like this:

```bash
var1="value1" var2="value2" python script.py args
```

I would like to be able to log the entire command typed in the shell prompt, that is:

- script name
- script arguments
- environment variables defined before the command (`var1` and `var2`)

The first two points can be done with `sys.argv`, but at the moment I cannot distinguish between previously defined variables and `var1` and `var2`.

---

## Edit

Added some context to clarify my intents.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my instinct is that that won't be possible.  The environment is basically just one blob of key-value pairs; your program just gets the whole thing and doesn't know where it came from or how it was constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear what are you trying to distinguish.  I guess these are your cases:

```bash
export var1="value1"
python script.py args
### vs
var1="value1" python script.py args
```

If I'm correct then it's impossible to do from Python (or really any language).  It is a shell feature to set/override environmental variable when running the command, so the process gets the full environment as a dictionary (or a hash map if you will), and there's no difference between environment variables by how they've been set.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use os.environ to set the environment variables inside the script?

you can get initial environment variables

```
for k,v in os.environ.items():
  print(f"{k}={v}")
```

and then you can set yours:

```
os.envrion["var1"]=value1
os.envrion["var2"]=value2
```

Comment: Because the environment variable represent configuration option for my script and I want to be able to change them at script invocation time.

Comment: @IvanProsperi94: Then you can add command-line options to your script to override the environment settings.

Comment: This is not an option unfortunately, actually this is why the problem arises, as I do not use command line options. The configuration is handled by Pydantic, and is parsed from a JSON file and the environment variables are the way to override configs from the JSON. Thank you again for your comments.